# How do you do a nested loop, where one of the variables of the outter loop runs in the inner loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, nested-loops

I have three dictionaries with coordinates looking like this:

**First one `one_crime_cord`** Containing a unique crime

```
(34.0141, -118.2978)
```

**Second one `crime_cord`** Containing multiple crimes

```
{0: (34.0141, -118.2978), 1: (34.0459, -118.2545), 2: (34.1847, -118.44)}
```

**Third one `neigh_cord`** Containing multiple neighborhoods

```
{'Acton': (34.497355239240854, -118.1698101922935), 'Adams-Normandie': (34.03146149912416, -118.30020800000014), 'Agoura Hills': (34.146736499122795, -118.75988450000015)}
```

I am trying to set a nested loop to get the distances from every crime to every neighborhood, and then input on an external data frame the neighborhood each crime belongs to based on the minimum distance.
So far, I've been able to do it for a single crime with these lines of code:
First Line of Code:

```
d3=[]
n_name=[]
for neigh_name, coord in neigh_cord.items():
    d2=distance (one_crime_coord,coord).m
    n_name.append(neigh_name)
    d3.append(d2)
    print(neigh_name,d2)
```

Output:

```
Acton           54886.9994821537
Adams-Normandie 1938.5858465073106
Agoura Hills    45115.60137307561
```

Second Line of Code:

```
distan_df=pd.DataFrame()
distan_df['Neighborhood_Name']=n_name;
distan_df['Distance to Crime']=d3
print(min(d3))
distan_df
index_min = np.argmin(d3)
print('------')
print('The Crime was commited in the neighborhood:')
print(distan_df.iloc[index_min,0])
```

Output:

```
472.2815720091788
------
The Crime was commited in the neighborhood:
Exposition Park
```

Third Line of Code:

```
test=la_crime_refined.copy()
test['Neighborhood']=''
test.head()
test.at[index_min,'Neighborhood']= distan_df.iloc[index_min,0]
display(test.iloc[index_min])
```

With the output in the data frame I'm trying to populate of:

```
    Neighborhood
83  Exposition Park
```

I figured I could do something similar using a nested loop:

```
distan_matrix=pd.DataFrame()
n_name2=[]
d5=[]
for crime_no,crime_coord in crime_cord.items():
    for neigh_name, coord in neigh_cord.items():
        d4=distance (crime_coord,coord).m
        n_name2.append(neigh_name)
        d5.append(d4)
    distan_matrix=pd.DataFrame()
    distan_matrix['Neighborhood_Name']=n_name2;
    distan_matrix['Distance to Crime']=d4
    index_min = np.argmin(d4)
    test.at[index_min,'Neighborhood']= distan_matrix.iloc[index_min,0]
    
print('------')
print('All Crimes have been assigned to a neighborhood')
test.head()
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-3e0c072951c2> in <module>
      2 n_name2=[]
      3 d5=[]
----> 4 for crime_no,crime_coord in crime_cord.items():
      5     for neigh_name, coord in neigh_cord.items():
      6         d4=distance (crime_coord,coord).m

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'
```

**The desired output would be a filled 'Neighborhood' column in `test` df**

```
    Neighborhood
1   North Holywood
2   Woodland Hills
3   Topanga Canyon
.
.
.
83  Exposition Park
.
.
.
```

However, I am not able to make it work. Is it because I'm using the outer loop variable in the inner loop? any suggestions?

Thank you and sorry for the length of the question!

Comment: The error message you show does not correspond to the code you show. The error is just a syntax error, and in the code you show, you have the correct syntax. I don't understand what you mean about a variable "running in" a given loop, but what you have shown is exactly how nested loops normally work.

Comment: There is an obvious syntax error in the error you posted. 

`items` is a method, and should be invoked with `.items()`, not `items[]`).

Also, your code doesn't match the output below, so double check all of those you posted.

Comment: My mistake, this is the actual error message I am currently getting @KarlKnechtel

Comment: The error is telling you that `crime_cord` is something other than what you described it as at the top of the question. You need to fix the underlying problem, which is not in the part of the code you have shown. Also, please try to choose better names. You are bound to confuse `crime_cord` with `crime_coord` at some point. My guess is that you already did exactly that in another `for` loop somewhere else, and replaced the dict with one of its values (which are tuples).

Answer (score 0):

On line 4, you have written `crime_cord.items[]`.

Your syntax error is here, and it's because crime_cord.items is a function, not a list. Try replacing that with `crime_cord.items()`.